# Three.js random mesh placement without overlap

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a series of circles which are randomly positioned on the scene (x,y). I was wondering if anyone knew of a solution to make sure that when randomly placed, the circles would not overlap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your loop when you place circles, take the randomized (x,y) coordinate, and get the distance to all of the existing circles (another loop) --> √((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2), if the distance is greater than the radii of both circles added together for EVERY circle, then you can place the circle, otherwise they overlap.

Comment: This make perfect sense, going to try it now.

Comment: Glad I could help

Comment: This worked great, for the distance calculation i ended up using:  `Math.hypot(x1 - x2, y1 - y2);`

Answer (score 0):

A statement checking to each circle's co-ordinates plus and minus its radius does not come within the co-ordinates of another circle plus and minus its radius in both the x and y direction could work